# EXCEPTION(most recent call first) IllegalStateException WorkManager is not initialized properly

Tags: android, android-workmanager

even though project does not even have work manager dependency and i do not use it at all
maybe some library SDK is using it ...
i get this in crash panel

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEzDZ.jpg)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG1BF.jpg)

Comment: Here is a discussion on the similar kind of  issue, maybe you get some hint https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138465476